# Django Model Form not saving to databased when filled out with AJAX data

Tags: python, ajax, django

I am trying to save data from an ajax call to the database by using a model form. I think the problem is that the form isnt valid, as `test` is printed when the code runs.

This is the Post part of the class based view

```
def post(self, request):

    set_name = request.POST.get('set_name', None)

    form = SetCreate(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit = False)
        instance.name = set_name
        teacher = Teacher.objects.get(user = request.user)
        instance.teacher = teacher
        instance.save()
    else:
        print('test')
```

This is the Form:

```
class SetCreate(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Set
        fields = ('name',
                'teacher',
                'students')
```

This is the AJAX:

```
function send(){
    var set_name = $('#class_name').val();
    //console.log(ids)
    //console.log(set_name)
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    ids = JSON.stringify(ids)
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: {
            'set_name': set_name,
            'student_ids': ids,
            },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            //location.href = data.url;//<--Redirect on success
        }
        });
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think the request data dictionary should have the keys as the model form expects. Like, `set_name` should be `name` as the fields in model form is `name`.

Comment: @SachinKukreja Nah didnt work. Like I said it doesn't think the form is valid, and doesnt enter that if statement

Comment: you can try to initialize the form in the shell and save it. The `form` object shows errors that it encountered using `form.errors`.

Comment: I figured out the fix, I just needed to remove the fields from the form and then it worked. I dont understand why this worked, so if someone can explain it to me I would appreciate it

Comment: My guess would be to try and add the ID of the model Set to the fields. I can't see your model but my guess is that neither of those 3 fields is the ID.